# Android: How to use open source VPN from an application in android 2.2 and above?

Tags: android, vpn

I found there are in-built package for VPN connectivity in Android 4.0+ but not for Android 4.0 below.. For using open source VPN the android phone below 4.0 needs to be ROOTED..

My question is how i can use or configure open VPN programatically within an application without rooting my device.

Is anyone explored on how to make/configure new VPN connection (Not a default one which is in Settings->Wireless->VPN) programatically in android 2.2 ?

Comment: did you find any solution? And you have mentioned "open VPN", does it use hidden APIs, if it does then can you please tell me one thing, by using hidden API, does we create a new vpn client or we access android's default client? And if it is android's client then can we still read the incoming and outgoing packets(like a vpn client reads the packets)...?

Comment: @user1204089 Sry i couldnt find anything iam waiting for replies to proceed.I need to knw is there any public openvpn ip to configure and test the openvpn app

Comment: You can set your PC as server

Comment: @user1204089 yes iam trying that only but many proxy issues. so only i asked is there any public openvpn server. And have u tested the toyvpn app? if so can u share ur knowledge

Comment: ToyVpn is not working for me. "Public openvpn server", I was trying and found one "SuperFreeVpn", but it did not work for me. As for setting your PC as server there should not be as such any issues...Is ur PC on a private network, then you can connect ur phone to the wifi/proxy of that network then it will not be problem

Comment: @user1204089 I am inside a corporate company due to policies they have my setup is on hold..And have u tried to setup OpenVpn server in ur system? Actually is there any other way to achevie my scenario which i mentioned in my question

Comment: Sorry, I did not try OpenVpn but http://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/ project mentions that they are using openVpn ,"With the new VPNService of Android API level 14+ (Ice Cream Sandwhich) it is possible to create a VPN service that does not root access. This project is a port of OpenVPN. "...

Comment: @user1204089 Sir i checked these links and i could not download the android project. I dont know what to do.. plz check [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177522/android-sample-code-to-use-own-vpn-connection-in-android-4-0-using-vpnservice-a) link. I compiled one project which i downloaded from [here](https://github.com/kghost/ics-openvpn) but i dont knw what values i need to give to make t work

Comment: About code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn: if u can not download it then u can browse it, click on souce and then on browse. About the valuse(server address etc), I don't think that you'll find any working vpn server address for free...ask your company's network administratot to give u compnay's server's address