# android connect app to internet using my VPN ip an port

Tags: android, proxy, connection, vpn

I'm using the **OneSignal Push SDK** in my app, but because of the new ***boycotts*** against our country, the user subscription in client side does not work. I want to see if there is a way to do this through programming and assigning VPNs to the source code to use a specific tunnel to connect to the network and perform operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177522/android-sample-code-to-use-own-vpn-connection-in-android-4-0-using-vpnservice-a

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use [Pushe](https://pushe.co/) in this case. It have good features and will meet your needs as well OneSignal does.